# Find mean of an array with both numbers and strings with Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, mean

I have a cell array (`arr_new`) that includes both numbers and strings and I want to find the mean value of each column (and ignoring the strings because those are points that I want to ignore in my calculation) using Matlab. The array is a 200x200 cell array and it is a combination of numbers and strings.

I tried to use this:

```
for k = 1:cols
    Y(k) = mean(arr_new(k,:));
end
```

But of course, it did not work because of the strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nCols = size(arr_new,2);
Y = nan(1, nCols); % pre-allocate
for k = 1:nCols
    isNum = cellfun(@isnumeric, arr_new(:,k)); % find number in the column
    Y(k) = mean(cell2mat(arr_new(isNum,k))); % convert to mat for mean
end
```

There are two tricks here. One is the use of `cellfun`, and the other is `cell2mat`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any of [*MATLAB R2015a (or later)*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/matlab/ref/mean.html#inputarg_nanflag) or *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox*, convert the strings/chars to `NaN` and then it is possible to find the mean ignoring those values after converting the [cell to a matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

```
k = cellfun(@isnumeric, arr_new);      %finding the indices of the numeric values
arr_new(~k)={NaN};                     %replacing the rest of the indices with NaN
%finding mean ignoring NaNs (which were chars/strings before)
Y = mean(cell2mat(arr_new),'omitnan'); %for MATLAB R2015a or later
% Use the following instead if you have R2014b or earlier with Stats and ML Toolbox:
% Y = nanmean(cell2mat(arr_new));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was successful when i tried it!!