# calculate mean from cell array with mixed numbers and strings

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array containing numbers and strings. Can someone help me with a code that can calculate the mean of the numbers in each row?

```
Mix = {

      'U'             [4.7506e+05]    [5.0141e+05]    [5.4067e+05]    [    542976]    [5.7124e+05]
      [3.9810e+05]    [4.4926e+05]    'U'             [    531440]    [5.3655e+05]    'O' 
      [3.0915e+05]    [3.6336e+05]    [3.7107e+05]    [3.8252e+05]    [3.3988e+05]    [4.3384e+05]
      'U'             'U'             'U'             'O'             'U'             [3.7107e+05]         
      'U'             [3.7107e+05]    'U'             [3.8252e+05]    'U'             'O'     }
```

I did solve it with some help from a previous question: [Find mean of an array with both numbers and strings with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995427/find-mean-of-an-array-with-both-numbers-and-strings-with-matlab)

Solution:

```
for k = 1:num
    isNum = cellfun(@isnumeric, Mix(k,:)); % find number in the row
    Y(k,1) = mean(cell2mat(Mix(k,isNum))); % convert to mat for mean
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: Hi Justin. Thanks for your interesting in helping. I did find a solution which I included in the question above.

Comment: If you don't want to use the non-numeric values in your cell array (as shown in your last couple of questions), just convert the non-numeric values to `NaN` so you can make your cell array a normal numeric array. Your life will become much simpler.

Comment: @beaker Thanks a lot for you comment. This is something I can use a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
Y = mean(str2double(cellfun(@num2str, Mix, 'UniformOutput', false)), 2, 'omitnan');
```

This works as follows:

1. `cellfun(@num2str, Mix, 'UniformOutput', false)` converts each cell to a string.
2. `str2double(...)`  converts each cell into a number. This gives `NaN` for cells that didn't originally contain a number. The result is a standard, numeric array.
3. `mean(..., 2, 'omitnan')` computes the mean of each row ignoring `NaN` values.

Comment: GREAT. Thanks Luis